# How can I set up env vars locally + in prod in a similar style?

Tags: node.js, jenkins, environment-variables

I am trying to set up a backend for a web app using Node.js. My goal is to create a system that can both be run locally and deployed on AWS. To deploy, I have a Jenkins pipeline that pulls from my git repo, builds the app, and deploys it using embedded Github + AWS credentials. This all works well.

I am struggling now to come up with a pattern to set up environment variables.

Initially I elected to use `.env` files to specify separate dev and prod environments. However, this is not ideal as the [npm page forbids it](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv#:%7E:text=Should%20I%20commit,values%20between%20environments). Additionally, this will require me to check my env files into source control, which goes against best practice.

My next idea was to use a `.env` file locally, and save some sort of environment variables directly in Jenkins separately that would be read into the pipeline’s environment (and thus into `process.env`) during building. However, I’m not a massive fan of this solution either as I’d prefer a common style of storing these env variables between local and prod to simplify the process of adding new env vars as necessary.

Is there a better solution?

Comment: Presumably "deployed to Amazon" is into an EC2 instance? How are you "building and deploying" it - what's stopping you setting the environment variables from Jenkins when you deploy it?

Comment: yes to EC2. Nothing is stopping me, I am just wondering if there is a better way of doing it since any time I want to add a new env var, I will need to both edit on the `.env` and within Jenkins. Both will be in different formats. This is doable, but I just wanted to see if there is a more generally accepted way of handling this.

Comment: Great! That's the normal way of doing it.

Comment: sounds good, will carry on with that method, thank you for letting me know!